# Is there a way to do analytics on who has downloaded my package

Tags: managed-package, appexchange

I am building a managed package. Currently it is not on App Exchange yet so we have only provided our customers with the install url. Is there way for us to find out who or how many people has downloaded our packages? Something like google analytics?

If it is not possible at the current stage, is it achievable after we published it through App Exchange?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After app exchange publication yes it is possible. Without publishing on App exchange it is not possible.

But you can use some workaround like create a Hierarchical Protected custom setting and set it to false.

Now give your customer a code and make a web service which make request to your org and check for same code and if it found the code and set the Custom setting to true.

Now in your code check if custom setting is false show a warning message to purchase license. You can create a static method a reference that in all classes.

```
Public class accessCheck9
{
  public static boolean csCheck()
 {
     return customsetting__c.getOrgdefaults().flag__c;
 }

}
```

You can keep this code unique for every customer and length of around 20 character so that it won't be easy to hack this. Although it will increase your development effort but its a one time process and then you have complete control who have installed your package.

There is one `License Management App` available to Manage all your license and other stuff. This App gives you complete control of who have installed your app and license , If its a paid app then payments. You can easily manage these things things with LMS.

Also Quoted from [Salesforce docs](https://partners.salesforce.com/s/appvendors)

> Selling with AppExchange provides all the tools you need to run your
>   business, including accepting payments, managing licenses, and
>   leveraging business management technology with the Partner Business
>   Org.

Comment: Thank you for this. Pretty interesting approach. Would you please also let me know how to track this after publishing in App Exchange? Any docs for that?

Comment: @LanceShi please check updated answer.